# Measuring peak memory usage using resource.getrusage

Tags: python, linux, resources

I am attempting to measure the peak memory usage of a long-running Python process using `resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss` (See [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html)).

Does `resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss` report peak memory usage for the lifetime of the process when called once just before exiting the process or do I need to periodically call it in a background thread as the process executes and take the largest of all the returned values? The documentation is somewhat unclear on the point.

Comment: Are you using a *nix or Windows?